# How to save a table in spark with dot in table name

Tags: database, apache-spark, save, schema, databricks

I have a schema named xxx and a table named yyy, I want to have three databases called bronze, silver and gold, I want them all to live in the same schema, so I wanted to call the databases xxx.bronce.yyy, xxx.silver.yyy, etc.

```
def read_options(options, format):
  if len(options)>1:
    return getattr(read_options(options[1:], format), "option")(options[0][0], options[0][1])
  else:
    return getattr(spark.read.format(format), "option")(options[0][0], options[0][1])

def write_table(path, table_name, format, mount_name, database, schema="default", saveMode="overwrite", options=None):
  if options:
    df = read_options(options, format).load(path)
  else:
    df = spark.read.format(format).load(path)

  df.write.mode(saveMode).saveAsTable(f"{schema}.{database}.{table_name}")
```

Here's my code, before I decided to write the tables as xxx.bronze.yyy, I was saving them just like xxx.yyy, so the last line of my code was:

`df.write.mode(saveMode).saveAsTable(f"{schema}.{table_name}")`

and it worked perfectly.

The error I am receiving is:

**AnalysisException:** Couldn't find a catalog to handle the identifier xxx.bronze.yyy.

in the saveAsTable line.

Comment: put table name into backquotes?

Comment: I got: `bronze.yyy` is not a valid name for tables/databases. Valid names only contain alphabet characters, numbers and _.

But I guess that answers my question! Thank you anyways!